# Horizontal lines shows after Ubuntu 14.04 installation

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, amd-radeon

After successful Ubuntu installation (14.04) I have a strange problem that horizontal lines appears from time to time on my screen. I check it on Windows7 and everything is OK. Previously before format I had got also Ubuntu 14.04 and I haven't got this problem. Only one line appears (in different places) and disappears in the same moment. Lines shows even on ubuntu log screen, it happens mostly on start, after some time it nearly stops.

video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mk9d5dgqtsqgn34/20160121_235234.mp4?dl=0
(sorry for low quality but you can see lines in 0:32, 0:47, 1:07, 1:33)

some info:

> ```
> przem@przem:~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, 
> Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV710/M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4330/4350/4550][1002:9552]
> ```

```
 przem@przem:~$ dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
[   12.840642] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[   12.986443] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[   12.986517] fb: switching to radeondrmfb from VESA VGA
[   12.988823] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (RV710 0x1002:0x9552 0x144D:0xC050).
[   12.988839] [drm] register mmio base: 0xCFEF0000
[   12.988841] [drm] register mmio size: 65536
[   12.989043] radeon 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 512M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000001FFFFFFF (512M used)
[   12.989047] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GTT: 1024M 0x0000000020000000 - 0x000000005FFFFFFF
[   12.989049] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=512M, BAR=256M
[   12.989051] [drm] RAM width 64bits DDR
[   12.989509] [drm] radeon: 512M of VRAM memory ready
[   12.989511] [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
[   12.989528] [drm] Loading RV710 Microcode
[   13.574567] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[   13.598034] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 262144, num gpu pages 262144
[   13.611820] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000000025E000).
[   13.611883] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[   13.611888] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c00 and cpu addr 0xffd36c00
[   13.611891] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000020000c0c and cpu addr 0xffd36c0c
[   13.612891] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fence driver on ring 5 use gpu addr 0x000000000005c598 and cpu addr 0xf8e9c598
[   13.612895] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   13.612897] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   13.612899] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[   13.612947] radeon 0000:01:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[   13.612981] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[   13.659269] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   13.659278] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 4 usecs
[   13.834216] [drm] ring test on 5 succeeded in 1 usecs
[   13.834225] [drm] UVD initialized successfully.
[   13.834439] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   13.834463] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[   14.480110] [drm] ib test on ring 5 succeeded
[   14.481403] [drm] radeon atom DIG backlight initialized
[   14.481406] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[   14.481408] [drm] Connector 0:
[   14.481410] [drm]   LVDS-1
[   14.481412] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e50 0x7e50 0x7e54 0x7e54 0x7e58 0x7e58 0x7e5c 0x7e5c
[   14.481414] [drm]   Encoders:
[   14.481415] [drm]     LCD1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY2
[   14.481417] [drm] Connector 1:
[   14.481418] [drm]   VGA-1
[   14.481420] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e40 0x7e40 0x7e44 0x7e44 0x7e48 0x7e48 0x7e4c 0x7e4c
[   14.481422] [drm]   Encoders:
[   14.481423] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[   14.481425] [drm] Connector 2:
[   14.481426] [drm]   HDMI-A-1
[   14.481428] [drm]   HPD1
[   14.481430] [drm]   DDC: 0x7fa0 0x7fa0 0x7fa4 0x7fa4 0x7fa8 0x7fa8 0x7fac 0x7fac
[   14.481431] [drm]   Encoders:
[   14.481433] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_UNIPHY
[   15.459388] [drm] fb mappable at 0xD045F000
[   15.459392] [drm] vram apper at 0xD0000000
[   15.459394] [drm] size 4325376
[   15.459396] [drm] fb depth is 24
[   15.459397] [drm]    pitch is 5632
[   15.459512] fbcon: radeondrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   15.459632] radeon 0000:01:00.0: fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[   15.459634] radeon 0000:01:00.0: registered panic notifier
[   15.478772] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.40.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
```

Please help me find the solution.